# How to chain rxjs Observable operations with angular2?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have a component getting data from a Service:

```
ngOnInit(): void
    {
        this.categoryService.getCategories().subscribe((data) => {
               this.categories=data;

            }
        )
    }
```

and here is the Service code:

```
getCategories(){
       return this.category.find({where: {clientId: this.userApi.getCurrentId()}}).map((data) => {
        return data;
        }, err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    };
```

the returned data structure is:

```
{"categoryName":"Google","id":"58591d2b7672d99910497bec","clientId":"585808f6737f6aad1985eab2"},{"categoryName":"Yahoo","id":"58591d4c7672d99910497bef","clientId":"585808f6737f6aad1985eab2"},{"categoryName":"Msn","id":"585d25f6ae4b2ecb056bc514","clientId":"585808f6737f6aad1985eab2"}
```

I have another method on `this.categories` called `countLinks(id)`; `id` is a category parameter like `585d25f6ae4b2ecb056bc514`, taken from the data structure.

`countLinks()` returns an observable containing all of the links for that particular category.

I would like to add to my data structure another property containing the number of links, per category id, of course.
Something like :

```
{"categoryName":"Google","id":"58591d2b7672d99910497bec",**"nblinks":"0"**,"clientId":"585808f6737f6aad1985eab2"},
{"categoryName":"Yahoo","id":"58591d4c7672d99910497bef",**"nblinks":"5"**,"clientId":"585808f6737f6aad1985eab2"},
{"categoryName":"Msn","id":"585d25f6ae4b2ecb056bc514",**"nblinks":"12"**,"clientId":"585808f6737f6aad1985eab2"}
```

To add information, categories is Array Type : 
[image: Preview data structure with Augury]

Any idea?

Comment: Just curious, what type of code is `this.category.find({where: {clientId: ID}})`? What type of object do you have in `this.category`?

Comment: This is an Observable

Comment: In that case, I think my answer below should work. :)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, what you are doing is horrible practice. Here is how I break down your problem:

1. Get a list of objects from backend.
2. Get an additional property for each of those objects from the backend, with ONE call for each object.

If you are hitting the same backend for both calls, you need to write an endpoint to get all the data you need, period. If you are hitting two backends, you need to pass an array of clientIds and get number of links in one call. If you don't control the second call backend, then fine, let's do it like outline in steps 1 and 2.

Your structure will need to look like this:

- Observable to get Data (you have this). A function to map this to ids only.
- A function to create observables from each received Id
- A `.forkJoin` Observable to make all your individual calls - this works like Q.all, if you are familiar with that.

I am too lazy to write the complete code for you, sorry, but basically, when you get your data, you need to create an Observable for EACH value returned, like this:

```
//This function will generate observables for you, when passed a param
function generateMockLinkCallObs(clientId){

  var mockLinksCall = new Rx.Observable(observer => {
    var mockCallTime = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5000) + 1000; 
    setTimeout(() => {
      var mockLinks = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12) + 1;  
      observer.next(mockLinks); 
    }, mockCallTime)
  })
  return mockLinksCall; 

}

//This just uses the function above to generate your observables for EACH object 
generateListOfObservableCalls(ids){
  var obsArray = [];
  var obs;
  ids.forEach(id => {
    obs = generateMockLinkCallObs(id);
    obsArray.push(obs);
  })

  return obsArray; 
}

//This just uses the above function. 
getNumberOfLinks(data){
  var ids = data.map(data => data.id)
  var observables = generateListOfObservableCalls(ids);
  return observables; 
}
```

So, to put it all together, you get your initial data:

```
httpWhatever.subscribe(
  next => {

  var observablesForIndividualCalls = getNumberOfLinks(next); 

  Observable.forkJoin(observablesForIndividualCalls)
   .subscribe((response) => {
      console.log(response[0], response[1]);
   });

  }
)
```

I over-simplified the last step, but forkJoin will only complete once you get results from all your individual calls.

And no, I don't know of a simpler way to do it, though it can definitely be cleaner.

Comment: Horrible? In fact I use loopback for the backend and an angular2 sdk for the front-end. The front-end sdk gives me methods for requesting categories for a particular user (depending on the relationship they both have together) and another method to get all the links for a particular category. I will have a look at the code you provided and that you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

What you describe is a typical use case for the [mergeMap()](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-mergeMap) operator.

Try this code:

```ts
getCategories() {
  return this.category.find({where: {clientId: ID}})
    .mergeMap(category =>
      countLinks(category.id).map(categoryLinks => {
        return Object.assign({}, category, { nblinks: categoryLinks.length })
      })
    );
};
```

I am mapping the first observable (returned by `this.category.find()`) to another observable (returned by `countLinks()`).

In the innermost `map()`, I end up with both the `category` and the `categoryLinks` and I merge them into a single object with `Object.assign()`.

---

*Side note:* Your original code is slightly confusing. You wrote "I have another method on this.categories called countLinks(id)" but you also wrote `this.categories=data`. How can you have a method on a data structure?.. I wrote my answer under the assumption that both `this.category.find()` and `countLinks()` return observables, but you'll have to adapt my solution to your specific code/situation.

Comment: Just tested the code you provided and thanks for that. Unfortunately, still getting **Property 'id' does not exist on type '{}[]'.)**. In fact, this.category is not of type Observable. It is of type categoryAPI. The return of **countLinks(category.id)** is of Observable type.

Comment: Well, my code is not meant to be used verbatim. I don't know the shape of YOUR API or the structure of YOU models... If you only have one observable (the inner `countLinks()` function), then I'm not sure what your question is. Maybe you just need to trigger one observable for each category and collect the results? You could use `combineLatest()` or `forkJoin()` for that.

Answer (score 0):

Create two interfaces. One to represent the base of the category and one that extends it.

```
interface ICategory {
    categoryName: string;
    id: string;
    clientId: string;
}

interface ICategoryExpanded extends ICategory {
    nbLinks: string;
}
```

Then use the .map() operator in RxJS to transform the data into the 2nd interface.

```
        this.getCategories().map((cats: ICategory[]) => {
                let mapCategories: ICategoryExpanded[] = [];
                cats.forEach((cat: ICategory) => {
                    let transformCat: ICategoryExpanded = <ICategoryExpanded>cat;
                    transformCat.nbLinks = this.countLinks(transformCat.id);
                    mapCategories = [...mapCategories, transformCat];
                });
                return mapCategories;
            })
            .subscribe((returnCategoriesExt) => this.categories = returnCategoriesExt);
```

That should handle what you want and return something like this:

```
[{ "categoryName": "Google", "id": "58591d2b7672d99910497bec", "clientId": "585808f6737f6aad1985eab2", "nbLinks": "5" }, 
{ "categoryName": "Yahoo", "id": "58591d4c7672d99910497bef", "clientId": "585808f6737f6aad1985eab2", "nbLinks": "5" }, 
{ "categoryName": "Msn", "id": "585d25f6ae4b2ecb056bc514", "clientId": "585808f6737f6aad1985eab2", "nbLinks": "5" }]
```